# Dismissible widget flutter , disable multiple item swipe?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to disable swiping multiple list items (just like in gmail) in Dismissible Widget.
Swiping multple items removes incorrect items with below code. So i just dont want that feature.

Thanks....

Code Snippet :

```
return Dismissible(
          key: Key(todos[index].title),
          background: DeleteHint(),
          onDismissed: (direction) async {
            final todo = todos.elementAt(index);
            _todoListKey.currentState
                .removeItem(index, (context, animation) => SizedBox());
            removeTodo = true;
            todos.removeAt(index);
            Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
            Scaffold.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Deleted"),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
      action: SnackBarAction(
          label: "undo",
          onPressed: () async {
            removeTodo = false;
            _todoListKey.currentState.insertItem(index);
            todos.insert(index, todo);
          }),
                ))
                .closed
                .then((value) {
              if (removeTodo)
                BlocProvider.of<TodoblocBloc>(context)
        .add(DeleteTodo(title: todo.title, index: index));
              removeTodo = false;
            });
          },
```

Comment: This key should be unique, I guess they have some similar items

Comment: @jitsm555 nope. I dont have any similar items.  All keys are unique.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this issue in couple of items only?